# Getting data before Angular renders (Angular 2+)

Tags: javascript, angular, voice

I need this code to execute before I render the html. Any Ideas? I've looked and Promises, Callbacks, and Observables

```
  voices;

  ngOnInit() {
    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
      speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
        this.voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: do it in the constructor

Comment: I'm curious - why must it run before the HTML is rendered?

Comment: If you need to execute code (such as getting data) before loading a route, you can use a route resolver service. See the docs for resolvers here: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: I think the route resolver is the correct way to go. I forgot about that construct. I tried putting it in the constructor, no dice.

Comment: I need to populate a drop down choice of voices for the user to choose from if the browser api allows for it.

Comment: Funny, DeborahK. I’ve been through two of your tutorials on Pluralsight! Awesome that you answered my questions.